# Early to mid 80s, children's sci-fi (quiz?) show; live audience, shouty host called 'Captain...' something or other

Tags: story-identification, tv

I was very young when this was on (I think) Children's BBC in the after school slot. There was a live audience of children, wearing brown robes/habits(?). They were supposed to be pupils or cadets of some kind. I'm not sure if this was a game show, exactly, or a story telling game in which the outcome of the 'adventure/mission' depended on participation. The setting was meant to be another planet, or possibly a spacecraft. The host was a man called the Captain, or maybe 'Commander'. All I remember was that after each illustrated segment/chapter (no animation or pre-recordings, just pictures on a screen), he would wind up the audience to a cheering/shouting pitch, then bellow "Silence!", with a sweep of his hand.  Does anyone have any idea what this was?

Answer (score 15):

There's not much information online about it, but is it possible this is [*Captain Zep - Space Detective*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0147754/)?

[image: Set of "Captain Zep - Space Detective"]

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Zep_%E2%80%93_Space_Detective) says this about the show:

> ***Captain Zep – Space Detective*** is a British television children's series produced by the BBC **between 1983 and 1984.**
>
> Constructed as part drama and **part quiz game**, *Captain Zep* featured mysteries that would be **solved by the child audience** in the studio, along with a write-in competition for viewers. The **child audience were dressed in futuristic clothes and had gelled hair**. The series was also notable for its combination of live action and animation, where the cast would interact with drawn alien characters amidst drawn backgrounds.

(Emphasis mine)

Comment: Given the uniforms, are you sure that's not a clown college?

Comment: There's a full episode on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xow3fJzLEP4 and it seems to match the question pretty well (students in robes helping solve the mystery, a Captain, a spaceship, illustrated segments...)

Comment: @Spencer "I’ll thank you not to refer to Princeton that way!"

Comment: YES!!! Thank you so much! That has been bugging me for *years*.

Comment: @pietro2 If this is correct you should click on the checkmark under the voting arrows in the upper-left corner of the answer.  That will mark it as correct, which will help future searchers find the answer more easily.